# Single static HTML file: how can I serve it efficiently?

Tags: html

Good afternoon.

I have a domain and server that I've procured for non-HTML services. Should anyone stumble across port 80 of this server, I'd like to serve them a page explaining what the domain & server is for, instead of just 404'ing them.

How can I serve one small, static, independent (i.e.: no images or CSS) HTML file, with a minimum of effort (meaning both a smooth setup for me, and minimum CPU expense).

The server contains an untouched installation of ArchLinux, and I'm open to solutions in any language.

(Note: I am a slight newbie when it comes to this, so forgive me if this question seems trivial or obvious.)

Thank you.

Comment: Currently your domain point to port 80? And do you explicitly make it www.domain.com:XX for some other service?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this serverfault article: https://serverfault.com/questions/7778/suggest-a-lightning-fast-feature-light-secure-linux-web-server-to-serve-static

It should point you in the right direction.  This isn't exactly a programming question anyways.